# Finding Probability&Confidence that a streak continue to occur once it has occurred

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

I am counting streaks that occur in financial data (consecutive positive increases or decreases). I want to know with what certainty a streak is likely to continue once it occurs and continues to occur. For example, one part of my data looks like
streaks of

5: 84

of 6: 52

of 7: 28

of 8: 11

of 9: 5

of 10: 2

of 12: 2

Total 184 streaks.

So how do I tell with what confidence&probability (I dont really know the difference in this case and would like to know both) a streak of 5 will continue to 6, 6 to 7, etc. How can I get these estimates for streaks that didn't occur like of 11 or 13?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Computing confidence or probabilities requires choosing a model for your data. 
There are many ways you could do this, each involving different levels of difficulty in estimation and assumptions; for instance, whether you want to use a time series method to model the underlying "up vs down process" versus trying to fit a probability distribution to try to model the streaks and their size itself. (The former case makes it easy to compute the chance of streaks continuing; the latter is what would be necessary to compute confidences.)

---

Anyway, here is a simple idea: use a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). 
A common assumption here is *time-homogeneity*, which says that the distributions governing the process do not change over time.
An order $k$ Markov chain means that the value of the process at time $t$ depends only on the last $k$ values.
Specifically, for example:
\begin{align*}
P(X_t=x_t|X_{t-1} = x_{t-1},\ldots,X_0=x_0)
&= P(X_t=x_t|X_{t-1}=x_{t-1},\ldots,X_{t-k}=x_{t-k})
\end{align*}
where $x_i=U$ means it moved up and $x_j=D$ means it moved down.

You then have to fit your Markov chain to the data (i.e. estimate the various transition probabilities).

For instance, for $k=1$, the transition probabilities can be written as a matrix:
$$
P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
P(X_t=U|X_{t-1}=U) & P(X_t=D|X_{t-1}=U)\\
P(X_t=U|X_{t-1}=D) & P(X_t=D|X_{t-1}=D)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In this highly simplified case, one can compute the probability of an "up" streak continuing as just $P(X_t=U|X_{t-1}=U)$.

You can then compute the probability of a streak occurring directly as well, e.g. a streak of size 3, starting from $ X_t=D $, as 
$$P(X_{t+3}=U|X_{t+2}=U)\,P(X_{t+2}=U|X_{t+1}=U)\,P(X_{t+1}=U|X_{t}=D)$$

---

Also, since you are using financial data, you might want to consider continuous time stochastic process models instead. E.g. for stock prices a simple model is [geometric Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion), and there are more sophisticated ones (e.g. [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_volatility)).